# Python, Returning object class names by a function

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and this is my first question here. Hope any of you guys will be able to help me out.
I'm trying to call values inside an object from an external program. The object that I'm trying to access is given in a class (as i uderstand it), and the name of the class may change according to X, see below:

[External programs object and class information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgwF2.png)

I want to be able to call information from Phase_6 in this case, however it could be Phase_12 in another case. I was considering making a function where i could have the _'Number' as an input. But I can't seem to find any information of how to do such.
I was thinking of something like using +str(X), as I do when plotting. But as it is probably not a string, it doesn't work out.

[My proposed code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLexc.png)

Ive read that bpy in Blender may be able to replace the name of the class that i want to return, however I'm not sure if it'll work, and I dont want to switch editor :)

Hope you guys can help me out,
Joachim

Comment: Please paste your code here. Pictures, and even worse, links to them, make the post difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, one could use `getattr`.

```
x = 6
result = getattr(g_o, 'phase_'+str(x)).Info.SumMsf.value
```

Thanks anyway - And I'll work on the pictures

Joachim